# spring config server default properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to serve up config for multiple applications, while providing reasonable defaults - I (apparently incorrectly) assumed that spring cloud config would serve the following property sources if I put in git the following files (using spring.app.name=foo, spring.profiles.active=bar & all on the server/git):

```
application.properties
application-bar.properties
foo.properties
foo-bar.properties
```

with each lower file overwriting/appending to the upper ones.  The bottom 3 return - but is there no way to make a server-side 'application.properties' for all applications (to enforce consistent logging location standards, for instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause (which will happen 90% of the time you post a question publicly) the application.properties file was .gitignored!